# Kivy .apk [ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists] on only Android

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

Im trying to create kind of application.I'm running and testing my application on my Linux,Pycharm succesfully.After creating .apk file and opening in my android device, it's closing immediately.

**main.py:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class Main(Screen):
    titletop = StringProperty('')
    user_name = StringProperty('')
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.search_for_user)
    def search_for_user(self,*args):
        try:
            with open('Datas/user.txt','r') as txt:
                self.user_name = txt.readlines()[0]
        except:
            confirm_but = MDRaisedButton(text='Create', md_bg_color=[0, 0, 1, 1],on_release=self.confirm_new_user_name)
            content = Content1()
            self.ask_user_dialog = MDDialog(size_hint=(.75,.5),auto_dismiss=False,title='Create User',type='custom',content_cls=content,buttons=[confirm_but])
            self.ask_user_dialog.open()
    def confirm_new_user_name(self,*args):
        self.user_name = self.ask_user_dialog.content_cls.user_tinput.text
        print('New User Name:',self.user_name)
        self.ask_user_dialog.dismiss()
class Content1(BoxLayout):
    user_tinput = ObjectProperty()
class Tabs(FloatLayout,MDTabsBase):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class mma(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mma().run()
```

**mma.kv:**

```
<SM>:
    Main:
        name: 'mainpagename'
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: root.titletop
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: root.t1()]]
            right_action_items: [["restart", lambda x: root.t2()],["send", lambda x: root.t3()]]
            md_bg_color: 165/255,165/255,141/255,1
            specific_text_color: 54/255,73/255,88/255,1
        MDTabs:
            background_color: 165/255,165/255,141/255,1
            Tabs:
                text: 'Tab1'
            Tabs:
                text: 'Tab2'
            Tabs:
                text: 'Tab3'
<Content1>:
    user_tinput:user_tinput_kv
    size_hint_y:None
    height: '50sp'
    MDTextField:
        id: user_tinput_kv
```

**This is my buildozer.init file:**

> **requirements = python3, sdl2_ttf==2.0.15, kivy==1.11.1, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip**

> **osx.python_version = 3**

> **osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1**

> **I didn't change these [default]:** android.api,android.minapi,android.sdk,android.ndk and android.ndk_api

> I'm creating .apk with this code: "buildozer android debug deploy run"

**And lastly, its my android log part:**

```
08-15 01:50:37.172 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
08-15 01:50:37.192 24584 24654 E libEGL  : validate_display:91 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-15 01:50:37.192 24584 24654 V SDL     : setOrientation() orientation=-1 width=800 height=600 resizable=true hint=
08-15 01:50:37.197 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
08-15 01:50:37.198 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
08-15 01:50:37.199 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@415.0 (GIT@1604d02, I97efb879e3, 1569445919) (Date:09/25/19)'>
08-15 01:50:37.199 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
08-15 01:50:37.199 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
08-15 01:50:37.199 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
08-15 01:50:37.200 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
08-15 01:50:37.200 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
08-15 01:50:37.234 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
08-15 01:50:37.235 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
08-15 01:50:37.438 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
08-15 01:50:37.667 24584 24654 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
08-15 01:50:37.667 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
08-15 01:50:37.795 24584 24654 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
08-15 01:50:37.795 24584 24654 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-15 01:50:37.795 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 42, in <module>
08-15 01:50:37.795 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
08-15 01:50:37.796 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
08-15 01:50:37.796 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
08-15 01:50:37.796 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
08-15 01:50:37.797 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 348, in idle
08-15 01:50:37.797 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/clock.py", line 598, in tick_draw
08-15 01:50:37.797 24584 24654 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 427, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
08-15 01:50:37.797 24584 24654 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 467, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
08-15 01:50:37.798 24584 24654 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 465, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame
08-15 01:50:37.798 24584 24654 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
08-15 01:50:37.798 24584 24654 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
08-15 01:50:37.799 24584 24654 I python  :    File "/home/mertma/Kivy_Projects/Project_1/kivmob-quickstart/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
08-15 01:50:37.799 24584 24654 I python  :  ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
08-15 01:50:37.799 24584 24654 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

As you can see, i am getting **ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists**. I did search for this error.And i tried to give different names to ObjectProperty's .py and .kv sides.Result was same.I removed .buildozer file and restarted but result was same.I can't understand why i get this error.Please help me and others. Thanks already..

Comment: Dublicate. Use Kivy kivy 2.0.0rc3 version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372033/kivymd-right-left-action-items-causes-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KivyMD - right/left\_action\_items causes "weakly-referenced object no longer exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372033/kivymd-right-left-action-items-causes-weakly-referenced-object-no-longer-exis)